# Visual Studio 2015 リモートデバッグでフォルダーを作成できないとエラーがでる

Tags: visual-studio

いつもお世話になっています。

VisualStudio2015でUniversal Windowsアプリを開発しようとしています。
ターゲットの端末がWin10で開発環境がWin8.1です。
Win10のPCにリモートデバッグのクライアントをインストールし、Win8.1のPCからデバッグ起動を行おうとすると、
「ベース レイアウト フォルダー C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles で、アプリケーション パッケージ 448d090a-2cc5-4c0b-8930-48310156e036|VS.Debug_x64.xxxxx|CN=xxxxx|448d090a-2cc5-4c0b-8930-48310156e036VS.Debug_x64.xxxxx のルート フォルダーを生成できませんでした。パスに無効な文字が含まれています。」
というエラーが発生して起動することができません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

作成しようとしているフォルダ名にパイプ'|'が入っているためにフォルダを作成できない様なのですが、何か対処法はありませんでしょうか？

使用しているVisual Studioは
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25421.03 Update 3
です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/
のURLのコメントに同様の質問が載っており、リモートデバッガーのクライアント側を最新にアップデートしてくださいとのことでした。
(「DEP4300」でページ内検索していただくと見つかります。)

リモートデバッガーのクライアントをアップデートしたら無事に起動できました。

お騒がせしました。